# How to create and login a frontend user (feuser) in typo3 manually/programmatically?

Tags: authentication, typo3, frontend, felogin

I want to create and login a frontend user in typo3 and I should be able to see user logged-in in login form. FYI Users are getting added to `fe_user` table in database but are not getting logged in.

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->forceSetCookie = TRUE;
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->start();
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user);
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $user;
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('user', 'fe_typo_user', $user);
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData('user', TRUE);
                    $this->ses_id = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
                    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);
                    $setSessionCookieMethod = $reflection->getMethod('setSessionCookie');
                    $setSessionCookieMethod->setAccessible(TRUE);
                    $setSessionCookieMethod->invoke($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user);
                    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SVCONF']['auth']['setup']['FE_alwaysFetchUser'] = true;
                    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SVCONF']['auth']['setup']['FE_alwaysAuthUser'] = true;
                    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['felogin']['login_confirmed'] = true;
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->loginUser = 1;
```

[image: expected this : [https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBBkn.png]
right now getting this [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjBlo.png]

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me in 7.6-9.5:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->checkPid = 0;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->dontSetCookie = FALSE;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->start();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession(['uid' => $userUid]);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->initUserGroups();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->loginSessionStarted = TRUE;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
```

Comment: How and where are you setting $userUid ? and how are you creating user ?

Comment: Its set by TYPO3/MySQL once you create a new fe_user in the database.
Use the uid of the created user for $userUid.

My posted code is just the login.

Comment: I have tried this code but I still cant get login user after creating it. But cookie is getting generated. Still I can't see user logged-in in login form

Comment: Does it work if you refresh the page (F5) after the login?

Comment: NO. I have tried refreshing code a lot of time. I can see cookie being generated in applications tab of google chrome but not in response when checked in Network's tab after response of the submitted form. I have no idea whats wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Typo3 Authentication services to implement your own user login functionality
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Authentication/Index.html